Vue component error handling with onErrorCaptured
We have specific components that have to be handled specially in regard to error logging. We are using Sentry and need to apply specific tags to possible errors when they are thrown in a specific component. Ideally, I want to create a single composable that could take care of this.
Now, I tried to use the onErrorCaptured hook, but it seems to only work for child components. I have seen multiple examples of a generic ErrorBoundary component online, which wrap an actual component so that It should work.
I prepared this example code (here's a playground link)
App.vue
<script setup>
import ErrorBoundary from './ErrorBoundary.vue';
import { onErrorCaptured } from 'vue';

function test(){
  throw new Error('TestError');
}
onErrorCaptured(error => {
  alert('From App.vue')
})
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <ErrorBoundary>    
      <button @click="test()">Force Error inside Boundary</button>
    </ErrorBoundary>
    <button @click="test()">Force Error outside Boundary</button>
  </div>  
</template>

ErrorBoundary.vue
<script setup>
import { onErrorCaptured } from 'vue';

onErrorCaptured(e => {
  alert('From ErrorBoundary.vue');
})
</script>

<template>
  <div>    
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>

I would expect that clicking on the button "Force Error inside Boundary" will show the alert from ErrorBoundary.vue but it does show the other one from App.vue. Clicking the other button will just throw an unhandled error.
What am I missing here?

The errors are propagated through the hierarchy and parents can catch them. However, your second call occurs in the same component and can be caught via its parent. https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-lifecycle#onerrorcaptured. You can leverage the global error handling mechanism (app.config.errorHandler) catching all errors at once; https://vuejs.org/api/application.html#app-config-errorhandler
